# Factoring a quadratic equation with complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm very new to complex numbers and am having some difficulty factoring a quadratic polynomial: $$x^2-2x+10.$$ Using the quadratic formula gives $$x=\frac{4 \pm\sqrt{4-2(1)10}}{2(1)}=\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{-36}}{2}=1 \pm 6i$$

But the computer gives me $(x-1+3i)(x-1-3i)$

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The 2 divides the whole expression not only the real part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quadratic formula is

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

So you should have

$$x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-4(1)10}}{2(1)}=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-36}}{2}=\frac 22\pm\frac {6i}2=1\pm3i$$

Do you see the differences with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just check which values of $x$ satisfy the equation. For $x=1+6i$,

$$(1+6i)^2 -2(1+6i) + 10 = 1 -12i - 36 - 2 + 12i + 10 = -27\ne 0 $$

While for $x=1+3i$,

$$(1+3i)^2 - 2(1+3i) + 10 = 1 - 6i - 9 - 2 + 6i + 10 = 0. $$

Remember that for a quadratic polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, a complex number $x+yi$ is a root of $p$ if and only if $x-yi$ is a root (you can verify this by a direct computation). So we see that the roots are $1\pm3i$.